# xml to R dataframe

Tags: xml, r

I am trying to store all the data in the below xml file as 1 or numerous data frames in R.  So far, only able to parse the first SubCategory and store it in a df.  Would like to store all the further data in the xml file in 1 or numerous dataframes - whichever is an easier solution.  Any suggestions?

My code:

```
library(XML)
data<-xmlParse("http://advisory.mtanyct.info/LPUWebServices/CurrentLostProperty.aspx")
xml_data <- xmlToList(data)
SubCategory<- data.frame(as.list(xml_data[["Category"]][["SubCategory"]]))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `xmlAttrsToDataFrame`

```
x <- lapply(data["//Category"], XML:::xmlAttrsToDataFrame)
names(x) <- xpathSApply(data, "//Category", xmlGetAttr, "Category")
library(plyr)
ldply(x, data.frame, .id="Category")
           Category              SubCategory count
1  Home Furnishings Wall and Window Covering    79
2  Home Furnishings                Ornaments    49
3  Home Furnishings               Appliances    97
4  Home Furnishings                    Linen   971
5  Home Furnishings           Floor Covering    30
6  Home Furnishings    All Other Furnishings   557
7  Home Furnishings                 Dishware   609
8  Sports Equipment                     Bats    13
9  Sports Equipment                  Scooter    64
10 Sports Equipment                Golf Club     5
...
221        Eye Wear               Sunglasses  2671
```

Comment: Thanks Chris, works well.  In order to store the top level node info into a df as well (NumberOfLostArticles and NumberOfItemsclaimed) I tried the following but not working out.  Can you provide your thoughts?

Comment: y <- lapply(data["/LostProperty"], XML:::xmlAttrsToDataFrame)
names(y) <- xpathSApply(data, "//LostProperty", xmlGetAttr, "LostProperty")
library(plyr)
b<-ldply(y, data.frame, .id="LostProperty")

Comment: Just check the XML file.  Like `Category`, those two nodes are children of `LostProperty` but do not have attributes, so maybe try  `xpathSApply(data, "//NumberOfLostArticles", xmlValue)`